# ffserver configuration to handle a large webm stream

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I'm setting up an ffserver for CCTV streams with 16 cameras - all the individual channels are streaming well with a config like:

```
<Feed 0.ffm>
File /tmp/0.ffm
FileMaxSize 5M
ACL allow 10.1.2.2
</Feed>

<Feed 0_webm.ffm>
File /tmp/0_webm.ffm
FileMaxSize 5M
ACL allow localhost
</Feed>

<Stream 0.mpg>
Feed 0.ffm
Format mpeg1video
NoAudio
VideoFrameRate 24
VideoBitRate 256
VideoSize 320x240
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoGopSize 12
</Stream>

<Stream 0.webm>
Feed 0_webm.ffm
Format webm
NoAudio
VideoCodec libvpx
VideoSize 320x240
VideoFrameRate 24
AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
AVOptionVideo cpu-used 0
AVOptionVideo qmin 1
AVOptionVideo qmax 31
AVOptionVideo quality good
PreRoll 0
StartSendOnKey
VideoBitRate 500K
</Stream>
```

And the associated ffmpeg calls made into upstart processes:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -standard ntsc -i /dev/video0 http://10.1.2.1:8090/0.ffm
```

and

```
ffmpeg -f mpegvideo -i http://localhost:8090/0.mpg -vcodec libvpx http://localhost:8090/0_webm.ffm
```

However when it comes to the large 4x4 grid overview of all the channels I'm having some issues with the ffserver.conf configuration.  Using this ffmpeg call made into a daemon I can reliably manage about 24-25 FPS (and have tested that it works by saving to a local file and playing it back via ffplay):

```
ffmpeg -i http://localhost:8090/0.webm -i http://localhost:8090/1.webm -i http://localhost:8090/2.webm -i http://localhost:8090/3.webm -i http://localhost:8090/4.webm -i http://localhost:8090/5.webm -i http://localhost:8090/6.webm -i http://localhost:8090/7.webm -i http://localhost:8090/8.webm -i http://localhost:8090/9.webm -i http://localhost:8090/10.webm -i http://localhost:8090/11.webm -i http://localhost:8090/12.webm -i http://localhost:8090/13.webm -i http://localhost:8090/14.webm -i http://localhost:8090/15.webm -filter_complex "
nullsrc=size=1280x960 [bg];
[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v0];
[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v1];
[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v2];
[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v3];
[4:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v4];
[5:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v5];
[6:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v6];
[7:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v7];
[8:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v8];
[9:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v9];
[10:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v10];
[11:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v11];
[12:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v12];
[13:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v13];
[14:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v14];
[15:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [v15];
[bg][v0] overlay=shortest=1 [bg];
[bg][v1] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [bg];
[bg][v2] overlay=shortest=1:x=640 [bg];
[bg][v3] overlay=shortest=1:x=960 [bg];
[bg][v4] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [bg];
[bg][v5] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240 [bg];
[bg][v6] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=240 [bg];
[bg][v7] overlay=shortest=1:x=960:y=240 [bg];
[bg][v8] overlay=shortest=1:y=480 [bg];[bg]
[v9] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=480 [bg];
[bg][v10] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=480 [bg];
[bg][v11] overlay=shortest=1:x=960:y=480 [bg];
[bg][v12] overlay=shortest=1:y=720 [bg];
[bg][v13] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=720 [bg];
[bg][v14] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=720 [bg];
[bg][v15] overlay=shortest=1:x=960:y=720" http://localhost:8090/all_webm.ffm
```

the issue comes when linking it to the ffserver - neither the ffmpeg process nor the ffserver process crash, yet the stream is inaccessible (while the single-channel .webm's work fine).  I've tried the same configuration as the smaller .webm's with the resolution changed along with this:

```
<Feed all_webm.ffm>
File /tmp/all_webm.ffm
FileMaxSize 20M
ACL allow localhost
</Feed>

<Stream all.webm>
Feed all_webm.ffm
Format webm
NoAudio
VideoCodec libvpx
VideoSize 1280x960
VideoFrameRate 24
AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
AVOptionVideo cpu-used 0
AVOptionVideo qmin [1|10]
AVOptionVideo qmax [31|42]
AVOptionVideo quality good
PreRoll 0
StartSendOnKey
VideoBitRate [512|700|800|1024|3M|3686400]
</Stream>
```

With every combination of the parameters shown with brackets around them and a few I can't remember.  Does anyone have a working configuration to stream large webm files with ffserver?

Edit: Added the feeds I'm using (no actual change, the all.webm stream is still broken in some unspecified manner).  Also I should have included this initially, but the ffplay output is as follows (it just hangs indefinitely):

```
ffplay http://10.1.1.15:8090/all.webm
ffplay version git-2013-03-17-ef3c888 Copyright (c) 2003-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 17 2013 19:21:22 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libspeex --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      52. 19.101 / 52. 19.101
  libavcodec     55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
  libavformat    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavfilter     3. 47.102 /  3. 47.102
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
    nan A-V:  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Another Edit:

Tested with the following:

```
ffmpeg -r 29.97 -f lavfi -i testsrc -s 1280x960 -r 29.97 http://localhost:8090/all_webm.ffm
```

Which works to stream the test stream (though slowly, it has to stop every couple of seconds to catch up in chrome, fails after the same period in firefox) - only gets 13 FPS.  So I tried breaking up the test and webm conversion portions as follows:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -s 1280x960 -r 29.97 http://localhost:8090/all.ffm
ffmpeg -r 29.97 -f mpegvideo -i http://localhost:8090/all.mpg -r 29.97 -vcodec libvpx http://localhost:8090/all_webm.ffm
```

The first command gets 29.97+ FPS, the second comes in at 13 FPS.

I'm not so worried about the FPS (13 FPS would be fine for the 4x4 grid), however this leads me to believe the issue may exist betweeh the long ffmpeg command (with the -format_complex option) and the import into ffserver in spite of the fact it records a perfectly valid .webm file when send to a local file instead of ffserver - still need help.

Another Edit:

Adding the tail of the large ffmpeg output being send to http:// localhost:8090/all_webm.ffm below, I've seen similar output in the smaller mpeg --> webm converting ffmpeg processes that work but the rate at which it differs so I didn't think it mattered (by having it record to a local .webm file and counting the duration being recorded while walking out in front of one of the cameras and back to the time I stopped the process the times synced up and the playback showed smooth 25 FPS motion), but I don't know enough about the process to rule it out completely (what follows is the end of the console output after pressing "q" to stop ffmpeg):

```
[Parsed_overlay_26 @ 0x37464e0] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 19 times
Buffer queue overflow, dropping. size=       4kB time=00:36:21.64 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
[Parsed_overlay_25 @ 0x374db20] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 28 times
[Parsed_overlay_17 @ 0x374ba40] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 11 times
[Parsed_overlay_20 @ 0x374e3c0] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 30 times
[Parsed_overlay_19 @ 0x374e4a0] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 28 times
[Parsed_overlay_32 @ 0x3749b20] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 17 times
[Parsed_overlay_24 @ 0x3745fc0] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[Parsed_overlay_23 @ 0x3751060] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
Buffer queue overflow, dropping. size=       4kB time=00:36:22.28 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
[Parsed_overlay_17 @ 0x374ba40] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 6 times
Buffer queue overflow, dropping. size=       4kB time=00:36:23.04 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
[Parsed_overlay_17 @ 0x374ba40] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 22 times
Buffer queue overflow, dropping. size=       4kB time=00:36:23.68 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
[Parsed_overlay_17 @ 0x374ba40] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 10 times
Buffer queue overflow, dropping. size=       4kB time=00:36:24.12 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
[Parsed_overlay_17 @ 0x374ba40] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 9 times
Buffer queue overflow, dropping. size=       4kB time=00:36:24.84 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
[Parsed_overlay_17 @ 0x374ba40] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Buffer queue overflow, dropping. size=       4kB time=00:36:25.32 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=54637 fps= 25 q=24.8 Lq=0.0 size=      48kB time=00:36:25.44 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s
video:172039kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -99.972099%
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide a `<feed all_webm.ffm> ... </feed>` before your `<Stream all.webm>`? I think that should do the trick, because probably FFserver doesn't know where to get the feed from.

If that doesn't work you can also test your feed from FFmpeg using `ffplay http://localhost:8090/all_webm.ffm`

Comment: I omitted it to save space because the feeds are pretty much all the same, I'll edit my post to show the feed I'm using.

Comment: Added ffplay output too (it hangs).

Comment: Why did you try `ffplay http://10.1.1.15:8090/all.webm`? I thought it was on your localhost: `ffplay http://localhost:8090/all_webm.ffm`?

Comment: The localhost's external IP is 10.1.1.15 - it's an Ubuntu server so I had to run ffplay from an external (Ubuntu desktop) machine.  The video processing all occurs on 10.1.1.15 (except for the initial read-in, which is on 10.1.2.2 (10.1.1.15 has a separate network interface set to 10.1.2.1 specifically because the two 16-ch video capture cards, out of some fluke of engineering, manage to life the server's pci-x risers out of their sockets whenever inserted, in spite of the fact they work with every other PCI card I have in the shop and the video pci's work in other machines).

Comment: 10.1.2.1 and 10.1.2.2 are connected via crossover cable, 10.1.2.2 is pretty low power, it just streams from pci cards to 10.1.2.1/10.1.1.15 (I tried having it handle the conversion to .webm too, but it was too slow for that so I had to put everything past that first ffmpeg line in my post on the primary video server [10.1.1.15/10.1.2.1]).

Comment: two 8-ch* video capture cards

Comment: The individual channels work, ie: ffplay http://10.1.1.15:8090/0.webm works fine, the ffplay http://10.1.1.15:8090/all.webm one does not and they have the same lack of ACL-restrictions (when I added restrictions to test if it was the security settings or not I got an error saying permission denied, so it is related to something else and there is connectivity).

Comment: Ah right, in my opinion that should work then. Have you also looked at the `#define MAX_STREAMS`? I've seen there could be settings for a maximum of 20 streams, so maybe that is bothering you right now?

Comment: In the source I compiled from #define MAX_STREAMS is set to 1024.  I compiled it following http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide in order to add support for libvpx encoding.